# Libraries to render vector-based maps in the browser

Tags: openstreetmap, web-mapping, vector, web-service, vector-tiles

Is there a open source JavaScript library like Leaflet or OpenLayers which can be used in a web or mobile application and loads vector-based maps instead of images? I only need the road information and some POIs.

The only library I found was [polymaps](https://github.com/simplegeo/polymaps) - but still I would need a server or service which serves the vector SVG data (preferable from OpenStreetMap). Also there is the nice Android project called [Mapsforge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/) but I would need it for a web application or other mobile devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We started a page to collect links and information about vector tiles in the OpenStreetMap Wiki (work in progress):

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles

Answer (score 10):

Update: since posting this, Mapbox released [Mapbox GL JS](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/), which does WebGL-based vector basemap rendering in browser.

At this point, there's no established option. The only fully-vector in-production map out there is Google's MapsGL, and that's very limited due to browser support & performance.

The closest you'll get with open source at the moment is [Kothic.js](https://github.com/kothic/kothic-js) and rolling your own tiles with Kothic's script.

Comment: +1 hey, this is cool! don't get why you got downvoted!

Answer (score 10):

For just drawing vectors, [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) or [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) will do just fine. Nothing new there.

For vector ***tiled*** maps (i.e different resolutions/levels of detail at different zoom levels),  [TileStache](https://github.com/migurski/TileStache) is a simple and good server. I have been using with lots of experiments with Polymaps (AFAIK, the only general-purpose working js tiled vector viewer). Some people have used [OpenLayers for adding tiled vector support](http://gaganb.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/tile-feature-strategy-in-openlayers/), but AFAIK, it has not been integrated to trunk in a year, so it probably won't in the near future for lack of interest.

TileStache (the server) itself is working very well. Nevertheless, I have found several bugs with Polymaps and since it is not being updated anymore (abandoned project), I cannot convince myself to use it in production (I'd have to maintain it myself... I can't justify it to myself just yet.)

My solution for me has been to write a custom OpenGL native vector renderer which is used in [AmigoCloud](http://www.amigocloud.com). In fact, that is how all maps are rendered in our service. For that purpose, TileStache has delivered quite well.

You want to look at the [TileStache Vector Provider](https://github.com/migurski/TileStache/blob/master/TileStache/Vector/__init__.py). For examples on how to use it, you can look at a very basic [vector test suite I wrote](https://github.com/migurski/TileStache/blob/master/tests/vector_tests.py).

Sadly, I don't think Leaflet has support for tiled vectors.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a simple tilestache demo out in the web?

Comment: The polymaps population density uses a tiled vector provider cache (i.e not running the tilestache server, but just a copy of what the ouput would look like). Looking at the code should make it obvious that it is vector tiled http://polymaps.org/ex/population.html . Sadly, the tilestache demos that are available online don't use the vector provider. Nevertheless, if you run tilestache-server locally and replace the demo urls for your localhost with a vector datasource (shapefile, postgis, etc) configured, it will work. Msg here for help if need be.

Comment: I am not agree with this answer especially this `For just drawing vectors, Leaflet or OpenLayers will do just fine. Nothing new there.` This will work if the vectors are to be overlayed, but how about if the entire map(all the base layer) are organized as vectors?

Comment: @giser That is why I make a distinction between "just drawing vectors" and "vector tiled maps". The second answer was the term I used "entire" maps made out of purely vectors. Here is an example of such a thing: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5593150

Comment: @RagiYaserBurhum: I am sorry, I misunderstand it.

Comment: no prob @giser :)

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly then both OpenLayers and Leaflet will load/show vector data.

For example

http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/

this loads a GeoJSON file onto the leaflet map which uses OSM via CloudMade in the background.

OpenLayers probably supports more different types of vector formats, like KML

http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/dynamic-text-layer.html

If you mean you are after a server to serve vector data onto the map then look at MapServer, GeoServer and ESRI ArcGIS Server which all will server vector data onto your map as a Web Feature Server (WFS).

Comment: I more mean the map itself as vector data not some features which I load onto the map.

Comment: serving a lot of data through vector type can hang or even kill browser, because of too many `<svg>` elements, you should keep this in mind

Comment: @Krystian That is if you render the map with SVG. Clearly you could render it with OpenGL/WebGL (as Google Maps does on the Android/iOS and in the experimental WebGL javascript maps).

Comment: @RagiYaserBurhum yeah, I didn't think about that, but still, in this particular case you can not use webGL, because of limitation in APIs ect..

Comment: You mean, limitations in browser support :) The API is well defined (albeit hard to use).

Comment: @RagiYaserBurhum yes firstly browser limitations, and secondly I think that merging ArcGIS JS API with WebGL (or sth.) would be massacre for developer and I'm not convincent about performance of such case. In other words IMO it would be overgrowth and there are other simple way to accomplish this kind of task. But for science or fun it could be interesting to test one of above. (I think we get tu much OT of subject)

Comment: The OP did not mention ArcGIS API so I wasn't assuming that (plenty of GIS can be done without ArcGIS). Yes, I agree that mixing ArcGIS JS with WebGL would be a pain. Tiled vectors are new - but they have a good chance of being the future. *Maybe*

Answer (score 2):

I found another interesting project called [GL-Solar](http://mike.teczno.com/notes/gl-solar-webgl-openstreetmap.html) which is based on webgl technology rather than SVG or canvas. Although it is in its early development this looks promising.

Also [MapCSS](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapCSS), [Cartagen](https://github.com/jywarren/cartagen/) and [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) should be mentioned. d3.js is used in the online osm editor [iD](http://ideditor.com/). There is also a blog post about [leaflet](http://www.giscloud.com/blog/gis-cloud-starts-html5-mapping-revolution) and html5 rendering.